# Negative exponential growth

Tags: calculus, soft-question, exponential-function, exponentiation, intuition

Thanks for reading!

I feel like I have an okay enough understanding of $e$.

This is how I understand it *(wordy definition incoming, but I'm trying to make it as complete as possible)*:

**By definition**, $e$ is by how much some principal amount $P$ gets scaled by if we allow that principal to produce **continuously**, at a rate such that it produces itself over an interval of $\Delta t$, for an interval of $\Delta t$, while also allowing every piece produced in that interval to produce at that same rate *(every piece produced in that interval would also produce itself if we allowed it to produce for $\Delta t$)*.

*Idk if that made any sense, but...mathematically:*

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=P*e$$

I can accept that **by definition**, that's what $e$ is.

However, what's befuddling me is, intuitively, WHY that would imply that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(1-\frac{1}{n})^n=P*\frac{1}{e}$$

Why is it that when something **shrinks** at a rate such that it would disappear in a single time interval $\Delta t$, but it does so continuously, after that time interval it'll have gotten **divided** by $e$?

Why not by some other number?

Had I not known this, or seem some proof, I would've never been able to predict that $e$ would show up again. Yet, there's got to be an intuitive way to see that it would!

I understand that even though it's shrinking at a rate of "decaying by itself in a time interval" the principal won't have disappeared in the time interval, because just like with exponential **growth** where the "rate of production" is increasing, with exponential **decay** the "rate of decaying" of the principal is slowing down, as the rate of decay at any given time is equal to the total current amount, which is decreasing.

But, I can't **see** that the number that our principal would get divided by is $e$!!!

After one time interval of $\Delta t$, why is it that when continuously shrinking at a rate equal to its current value, the principal **shrinks** by the same factor than it grew by in that same time interval with continuous **growth**?!?!

Why doesn't it shrink by some other factor? How can I intuitively see that $e$ would show up again?

Thanks!

Comment: If it helps: Shrinking is growth but with time flowing backwards.  I don't know why you say it would shrink to nothing in a single time interval.  It will do no such thing.

Comment: @fleablood that does help...I think. I'll have to think more about it. And no no, I probably worded it really badly, I didn't mean that the principal would shrink to nothing in a single time interval. I mean that because the principal is decreasing **continuously** at a rate of its current value per time interval, it **won't** decrease to nothing. If it decreased discretely once in the time interval, then we would have $P(1-1)^1$, which indeed would just mean it would get reduced to nothing.

Comment: Hmm...@fleablood I thought more about what you said....I like it. If I were to start with $P=\frac{P}{e}$, and grow continuously, I would get $P$ after the time interval is over. If I were to play the process in reverse, I would get $\frac{P}{e}$ after the time interval is over. However, that's only accepting that the shrinking IS the growing with time flowing backwards...and that's still confusing me a little. Yea, I have to think about it a bit more...

Comment: One would have to do some work to ensure the limits and product commute, and the last limit isn't totally trivial, but consider:
$\lim_n (1 + 1/n)^n \cdot \lim_n (1-1/n)^n \approx \lim_n \big ( (1 + 1/n) (1-1/n) \big )^n $ $= \lim_n (1 - 1/n^2)^n = 1.$ 
So they are multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n := (1+\frac 1n)^n$. We know this sequence converges to $e$.

It's intuitive that the sequence $b_n := (1-\frac 1n)^n$ converges to *something* between $0$ and $1$ inclusive, since the entire sequence lies between $0$ and $1$, so let's say it converges to $f$.

Then $a_nb_n = (1-\frac 1n)^n \cdot (1+\frac 1n)^n$ converges to $e\cdot f$.

But $a_nb_n = (1-\frac 1n)^n\cdot (1+\frac 1n)^n = ((1-\frac 1n)(1+\frac 1n))^n = (1-\frac 1{n^2})^n$. What does this converge to? Again, it needs to converge to *something* between $0$ and $1$, but this time we can use Bernoulli's inequality to find out that $(1-\frac 1{n^2})^n > 1 - \frac n{n^2} = 1-\frac 1n$. As $n$ grows large, this term goes to $1$, so by the squeeze theorem the sequence $a_nb_n$ has to converge to $1$.

Now we know that $e \cdot f = 1$, so $f = \frac 1e$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n.$$

So with $x=1$ you get $e^1=e$ and with $x=-1$ you get $e^{-1}=1/e$.

To see where the limit representation comes from, let's take the natural logarithm:

$$x=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right).$$

Using the Taylor expansion for log, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^2}{n^2}+\cdots\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x+O(1/n)=x.$$

Check out [this link also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2).

Comment: Yes yes I know. And thanks for the answer, +1! But let's say no one had ever defined $e^x$ that way yet. Would you have been able to predict that the principal would've gotten shrank by a factor of $e$?!!!

Comment: Could you explain *why* $e^x = [\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac 1n)]^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n$?  I don't think the OP will (or should) take this for granted without an explanaition.

Comment: @JoshuaRonis : Note that the expression for $e^x$ isn't a definition, rather it can be deduced from your definition of $e$ (for a fixed positive $x$, think about replacing $n$ with $n/x$ in your definition of $e$).

Comment: @fleablood correct, that's something I've never quite been able to grasp...in fact, I was thinking of asking a question about it right now!

Comment: @MPW hmm...so instead of growing by itself over the time interval, the principal would grow by $x$ times itself over the time interval? But that still doesn't help me see why it would get divided by $e$...

Answer (score 1):

Okay take the first case when calculating P*e. Now another thing you could do is instead of having $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ try instead $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n}$. As you might know anything raised to a negative exponent is just the reciprical of that. Then try to simplify that new expression via partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: +1, and thanks! But let's say I DIDN'T know that anything raised to a negative exponent is just the reciprocal of that! Then how would I be able to predict that my principal would've shrank by a factor of $e$?

Comment: The limit of $(1+1/n)^{-n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity is the limit of $(1-1/n)^n$ as $n$ goes to *negative* infinity.